# Using a stack to sort into the desired order

Tags: algorithm, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a stack of books that I want to sort from the original order to the desired order.
However, I'm only able to pull one book out of it's position at a time and put it on top. Another requirement is that I would have to process the original stack (in-place), which makes my optimal solution of using 2 stacks invalid.

Example:

(Original ordering)
A
B
C
D
E

(Desired ordering)
B
D
E
C
A

Operations this seems to require:

Remove every element until A and put it on top of the stack (now A is on the bottom as intended)

B
C
D
E
A

Remove D and E and put them on top (C is now in place)

D
E
B
C
A

Remove B and put it on top (the stack of books is sorted now)

B
D
E
C
A

I'm having trouble understanding how I would go around accomplishing this without going through the stack over and over multiple times and using a massive amount of memory. Is there a better way to do this? Would there be a data structure best for this use?

Edit: Not sure why I removed everything else instead of the target item...I could just move the target item to the top instead.

Comment: Use the recursion stack. :-)

Comment: The stack behaves differently though. In my problem I need to be able to pop any element in the "stack", which is not what a normal stack does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we already have the desired ordering of the books, we don't need to make any comparisons with other books; we simply use the desired ordering as a lookup for our original ordering.

Your question seems to imply that we have direct access as opposed to the traditional definition of a stack where you can only pop the top item off the stack. This makes things a lot easier.

Because we don't have the privilege of inserting a book at any position (only the top), we have to order the books as we go.

In your example, we have:

```
A  
B   // Original
C  
D  
E  

B  
D   // Desired
E  
C  
A
```

Assuming the bottom book is index 0, we can iterate through each book in the desired ordering, find the book in the original, remove it, and pop it to the top. Repeat until every index has been processed.

As shown in the image below, the numbers are the order the books get removed from the list, then pushed* back onto the top.

[image: The order we "pop" and "push" the books]

Note that popping* A in this example is unnecessary, but we are writing an algorithm that covers all scenarios.

Of course, since we do not know the location of the book we are looking for, we have to iterate through the whole list to find it. This makes our algorithm work in `O(N^2)` time.

This should be sufficient for most purposes. However, if you have a large number of books and need to squeeze more performance out of the algorithm, there is a small change we can make to get a better best case.

Again, we start from the bottom of the desired list and locate the corresponding book in the original list. But once we've found it and moved on to the second-from-bottom book in the desired list, we iterate through the original list, **but only for the book on top of our previous index**. This is where the optimization comes in. Instead of iterating through the whole list over and over, we simply look at the ones above the books we've already found. However, once we hit the top of the original list and do not find the desired book, we stop and fall back on the previous algorithm for the rest of the list.

I will use a different example to better illustrate the change. Keep in mind we start from the bottom of both lists (index 0).

[image: Small optimization for our original algorithm]

Notice the red `-`'s. These are books that are in the correct order, but may have other books between them that need to be popped. We continue with the current iteration through the original list until we hit the end of the list without finding our desired book. Once/when that occurs, we fallback to the previous algorithm (locate desired book in original list and pop it).

With this change, instead of doing 6 push/pops and iterating through the original list 6 times, we only have to do each 4 times. In a best case scenario (both lists are the same), this algorithm will never need to push/pop while the previous one would still do it for every single item. The worst case scenario (one list is the reverse of the other), both algorithms will run in the same time.

* *Note that I am saying "push/pop" as if this were a stack, but in this case, pop simply means removing from the list.*

Here's a sample implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> original = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> desired = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int books;

        books = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine(); // Remove extra newline character

        //Populate lists
        createBooksList(original, books, in);
        createBooksList(desired, books, in);

//            System.out.println("-------------PRE SORT-------------");
//            printList(original);

        books--;
        for (int i = books; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (original.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(desired.get(books))) {
                books--;
            }       
        }

        // Books that need to be removed from current position and put on top
        for (int i = books; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(desired.get(i));
            original.remove(findBook(original, desired.get(i)));
            original.add(0, desired.get(i));
        }
//            System.out.println("-------------POST SORT-------------");
//            printList(original);

        in.close();
    }

    private static void createBooksList(ArrayList<String> list, int books, Scanner in) {
        for (int i = 0; i < books; i++) {
            list.add(in.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private static void clearBooksList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        list.clear();
    }

    private static int findBook(ArrayList<String> list, String bookName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(bookName)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static void printList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
6
B
D
E
A
F
C
B
A
C
D
E
F
```

Output:

```
C
A
B
```

As for the preferred data structure, both an ArrayList and LinkedList would work fine. The main thing you are looking for is random-access. Both an ArrayList and LinkedList provide this, but ArrayList has an O(1) lookup time for elements, while LinkedList has O(n) because internally, it has to go through all the previous items to arrive at the index you want.

On the other hand, LinkedList provides an O(1) removal of items, while ArrayList has to remove an item, and shift every item behind it O(n). This is pretty expensive too.

So they both excel at one half of our problem, but I picked ArrayList because it has a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

First, load your original ordering into a linked list. Now, say `B0` is the book on the bottom of the desired ordering (`A` in your example). Find `B0` in the linked list, take it out of the list, and insert it at the start of the list (top of the pile).

Then, say `B1` is the second-from-bottom book in the desired ordering (`C` in your example). Find `B1` in the linked list, take it out of the list, put it on top of the pile.

And so on... This is `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  You always pick the largest book from the unsorted part and put it on top of it.  This requires you to move exactly N books.  The number of comparisons is much larger, but those are rather cheap as compared to the moves.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the desired ordering from the bottom up. First remove the bottom book in the desired ordering and put it on top. Then remove the second-to-bottom book in the desired ordering and put in on top. And so forth. This doesn't require any extra memory, and it's O(N^2) time for N books assuming that you have to search the stack for the book you want to move next.